Are there infinitely many possible thoughts?
First off, it is not quite clear how we define what a "thought" is and what it means for a thought to "be possible". I would like to take colloquial definitions, at least as far as possible one can come to answer the question:
"Are there infinitely many possible thoughts?"
My first thought and claim was that any thought must be determined by a finite sequence of brain states which in turn are determined by the particles the brain is made up of. Since each brain is made up of finitely many particles we would have the following statement:
If there are only finitely many possible positions for particles, then there are only finitely many possible thoughts.
However, it is not clear whether the premise is true. It would depend whether the space has infinitely many positions such as the four dimensional real space R^4 or the four dimensional space of rational numbers Q^4. However, if there would only be finitely many positions, for example considering the Planck length as the smallest unit of space measure, then the above premise would be true.
In addition to that, I think it may not be clear if a thought is really determined by the brain states or the particles the brain is made up of.
After some more thinking I came to the example of the natural numbers. If each natural number can be thought of, then the question could be affirmed. However, this is probably not true since numbers become to big to be thought of in the bounded lifespan of a human.
I had some more thoughts about this, but always came to some conclusion along the lines of the first try to answer the question from above. Then I came to the following conclusion:
If there is some finite abstract object which is made up of infinitely many parts which can each be thought of, then there are infinitely many possible thoughts. If not, then there are only finitely many thoughts.
What led me to believe the above is that we can always think of some object with some property. For example, a chair with some color. If there are infinitely many colors and I could think of the chair in each color, then there would be infinitely many possible thoughts. Another example is to consider one fixed length and if there would be infinitely many sublengths (similarly to the above positions to particles) and we could think of an object being at each of the sublengths, then we could affirm the question again.
But I have the feeling that the answer might be a circular argument.
I would like to hear some thoughts to the above question.
Edit:
It seems that there is confusion about the question. To make it a bit more precise:
Has the collection {Thought : Some human could think Thought}  infinitely many members?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There are an infinite number of possible thoughts. Consider the sequence of thoughts represented by
2 is greater than 1
3 is great than 2
4 is greater than 3
etc. For any number N that you choose, I can construct a sequence of thoughts using this sequence that is greater than N. Therefore there is no limit to the number of possible thoughts.
Your speculation about how thoughts are represented in the brain is not relevant to the question unless what you are really asking is whether there are an infinite number of possible representations of thoughts. A representation is a physical thing, so if that's what you mean, then this question just devolves to the question of whether there are an infinite number of physical things.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Yes, there are infinite many numbers, and thus an infinity of corresponding thoughts. See Dedekind's proof of the Axiom of Infinity. –
Mauro ALLEGRANZA

You ask:

Are there infinitely many possible thoughts?

It partially depends on your views in the debate between two metaphysical positions: actual and potential infinity, a question that goes back to at least Plato. Those who believe in actual infinity, the noble Sr. Allegranza among them, certainly accept such a premise. As a proxy for "thought" which is far more controversial than "word", let's lean on linguistics temporarily.
From a linguistics stand point, one can talk about permutations built on open categories such as nouns as a proxy. Thus, one might point out that even a construction such as "I am x" where x is a noun or adjective and such categories are open means that there are an infinite number of sentences in a language. Of course, that only kicks the can down the road since it becomes a question of "Are there an infinite number of nouns and adjectives?" Someone who answers in the affirmative on these questions is again leaning on their mathematical intuitions and beliefs about infinity.
Those of us with more empirical intuitions might lean on Bouwer's intuitionism (SEP) to move us from a logical to a psychological analysis of infinity. In this sense we are now in a better position to defend potential infinity in the sense that any physical system, such as the human body and brain, has empirically demonstrable limits. Thus, there is overwhelming empirical evidence that not even the universe is infinite in most regards, and certainly people fall short of the characteristics of the universe. If you subscribe to the big bang, and thoughts are a function of brains, then there was a time before brains and there probably will be a time after brains, and therefore words, as overwhelmingly large as such a count might become, are finite.
Of course, you muddy that metaphysical argument by using "thoughts", which is philosophically more controversial, because it's not even clear whether a thought constitutes a discrete event with finite dimensions. If one thinks about non-linguistic thoughts, how does one even conceive of quantification emotion? So all said, from an empirical perspective it's hard to make an argument that humans, who are essentially finite beings, could ever have an infinite number of thoughts or speak an infinite number of words.
ADDENDUM
Since you want me to address the question in the full scope, you have to understand there are ALSO other issues that impact the question, such as the debate over internalism and externalism in the philosophy of mind and one's views regarding mind-body dualism, such as whether you accept property dualism or identity monism as descriptions. In philosophy, all things are complicated, so until you rigorously define thought, mind, and body, having any coherent view would be difficult to claim.
Since you're looking for potential answers, let me lay out my pet theory, and maybe it will spark some thought. I approach philosophy and epistemology as a naturalist (SEP). I am also a property dualist. I also subscribe to embodied and extended cognition (SEP). I am also an intuitionist who believes in constructive mathematics (SEP). Now I roughly can combine these.
So, my brief metaphysical speculations are: Thoughts are mental objects which are reified parts of the mind which is a label for the domain of discourse that describes non-physical phenomenological experience. As such, thoughts and meaning never exist independently of minds, and minds never exist independently of bodies. Therefore, there are no "potential thoughts" floating around in space, and the only thoughts that every truly exist are those that are constructed or in more physicalist terminology, states of the brain and body. In this way, epistemic modality (SEP) is a bit misleading because it reifies abstractions in a way that makes conceivability a basis for existence when existence should be a measure of what is, and not some vague notion of what could be. Therefore, "potential thoughts" like "potential infinity" are useful fictions, and asking questions about them is like asking questions about whether or not goblins can ride unicorns. It is fun for discourse and a good Gedankspiel, but ultimately has no more bearing on discussions about physical reality, and is akin to debating how many angels, another popular fiction, can dance on the head of a pin.

I like that answer very much. It gives some nice perspectives I did not know about and addresses the non-sufficientness of colloquial definitions. Though, to the last bit "it's hard to make an argument that humans, who are essentially finite beings, could ever have an infinite number of thoughts or speak an infinite number of words": The question is not whether humans could have an infinite number of thoughts. The question is whether there are an infinite number of thoughts a human could think. Perhaps this is what you meant, but not said in that way.

Didn't answer the question because technically this site is actually meant for short, fact-based Q&A instead of personal philosophizing; and the answer is already long. I'll edit in a response momentarily.

I have that many waiting for my tea to steep.

No less an authority than Richard Dedekind attempted to "prove" the existence of N based on the infinity of thoughts, as it were.  The reference for this is in Beenakker's answer.
See pages 107 and following and pages 244 and following of Labyrinth of Thought: A History of Set Theory and Its Role in Modern Mathematics by José Ferreirós (2008).
Today few people would accept such a "proof" since the notion of "thought" is too ill-defined.
With regard to your correction: "Has the collection {Thought : Some human could think Thought} infinitely many members?" it could be mentioned that since there are finitely many humans, the putative possibility of infinitely many thoughts among all of them is equivalent to such a possibility for a single person.

In order to answer that, we first need to define what a thought actually is.
I'm going to say a thought is anything you could think instantaneously - if your thought requires more than an instant to think, it's multiple thoughts. For example, if you thought of a forest, that would be a thought, but if you thought of walking through a forest, and then walking out to a stream (not of walking out of a forest and seeing a stream, this would still be one thought), then that would be multiple thoughts.
Since you can't, for example, think an infinitely long number in one thought (even if you memorized 1000 digits of pi, you wouldn't be able to think all of them at once in a single instant), infinitely complex thoughts are impossible.
I think there also must be a finite number of single-thought concepts - for example, in a 16 by 16 size pixel image, there are a set number of arrangements of colored pixels we can see. Increase the size of the image to 1000 by 1000, and there's still a set number of arrangements. For the same reason that we can't think an infinitely large number, we can't make the image infinitely large, either - humans can't think in an infinitely high resolution. You could apply this to real life, as well - you can't see the bacteria on a leaf without a microscope.
If a thought can only be so long before it becomes two thoughts, and a thought can only be so large before we can't see it in full, a thought is limited - and therefore the set of all thoughts is also limited.

I would make a similar comment to the one from @l0b0 's answer here.

It is known that humans cannot remember arbitrarily large integers. Since this is the smallest known infinity, ℵ0, that means humans can't think infinitely many things.
Another reason is that any physical system has a finite number of states. Unless you posit some sort of unscientific definition of "thought" (like two identical states representing different thoughts at different times) or novel physics showing that there are in fact an infinite number of states of the universe, it follows that there are a finite number of thoughts.

But the thing is that it is not necessary that arbitrarily large numbers (or things for that matter) must be thinkable in order to have infinitely many possible thoughts . See the example of the chair with infinitely many colors. There we have some thing bounded in its complexity with infinitely many properties we could think of. But, then the question becomes whether there are actually infinitely many colors (or some other unit one could split up in infinitely many parts).

@FlynnFehre what really is the difference between a number that has too many digits to remember because it's a huge integer, vs too many digits to remember in the fractional part?

@FlynnFehre There can't be infinitely many colours, because there are only so many states matter can be in. "More than any human can possibly enumerate" is an extremely long way from "infinite".

I think this is the correct answer if we think of nature (in particular, brains) of moving between discrete states. This is actually somewhat implied by the quantum nature of nature. If, by contrast, we assume "things" are continuous there can be an infinite number of states and, hence, thoughts.

@benxyzzy I think you refer to "If there is some finite abstract object which is made up of infinitely many parts which can each be thought of, then there are infinitely many possible thoughts." What I meant with that is not a number with infinitely many digits. But rather some abstract thing X which we can think of which has infinitely many sub-instances X_i which we can also think of. The chair-example falls below that. There, chair is X and X_i is the chair with color i and i runs through the infinite colors. There, we do not have the problem of complexity in contrast to integers.

@l0b0 I dont understand what you mean with "There can't be infinitely many colours, because there are only so many states matter can be in." Could you elaborate?

@l0b0 if you define colour in terms of frequency of light, can't that take any value (maybe within some range)?

In theory it is possible for any frequency of light to exist. In practice, the number of colours which could ever be observed is finite, because the number of photons in the universe is finite. See for example this Q&A.

Your chair example, and your comment on this answer, invokes the way brains represent objects.
Very briefly, neuroscience models this as "neural representational spaces". A representational space is an abstract high-dimensional space wherein each point represents an object. Objects that are similar are closer together in the space, i.e. the distance between their points is small. The dimensions of the space are properties of the object (like colour) which our sensory systems have learned to extract because those features are good for discriminating the objects in question - hence the alternative name "feature spaces".
Face space is the biggest example, with dimensions possibly encoding things like face width, height, inter-eye distance etc. Basically those visual features that help us distinguish people from each other, so not e.g. nose position which is the same for everybody. We probably have a "chair space" too, though it won't be as developed (evolutionarily nor from learning) as face space.
Your question then, is how many distinct points can we get into such a feature space, summed over all such spaces in a brain, summed over all possible brains.
(In reality there are multiple face spaces so each face is represented multiple times. We have distinct face spaces for person recognition vs emotion detection, static vs dynamic facial information... Brains also stack perceptual representations into hierarchical streams so that spaces representing individual facial features are upstream of the "whole-face spaces" I've described, which in turn output to higher "whole-person" spaces etc. A single "thought" - viewing or imagining a face in this example - therefore strings together activation across several representational spaces, dependent on the specific perceptual task. I'll ignore this for simplicity)
I guess this is when considerations of finite vs infinite, integers vs reals, and "minimum lengths" like Planck come in. Take a point in one of these neural representational spaces and consider its coordinates: are they discrete or continuous valued? (for example)
Regarding the "implementation" of such spaces, dimensions are often equated to neurons, so the value of a coordinate is a neural firing rate. If you've got 10 neurons then at most you can have a 10D feature space (so you'd better hope it doesn't take many to discriminate the objects in question). In reality there is redundancy and the brain is a fuzzy statistical machine, so the literal mapping of feature -> neuron is not so clean.
Anyway regarding neural firing rates: they can't fire infinitely fast, but I don't think there's any restriction on the number of distinct values it can take between min and max. Neurons are biological rather than digital so just as a result of noise/imperfection, there will be diversity in the firing rates of a neuron. It's regarded as continuous-valued so far as I'm aware.
That said, given the noisiness of such representations it cannot be that literally every 'distinct' point in the space (i.e. comprising different sets of firing rates; coordinates) is taken to represent a distinct chair or face - people's identities would seem constantly changing! Instead we probably recognise a face via closest proximity of its representation in face space to said representations of faces from memory.
Regarding "chair space" and the "colour" feature specifically, this is akin to saying there's a minimum difference in colour below which you won't be able to distinguish two [otherwise identical] chairs. This is the just-noticeable difference of psychophysics, which is what you're looking for wrt consideration of 'perceptual fidelity', but note that it's defined as a difference between two stimuli. The idea is not individual stimuli spaced over a range (the feature dimension), but only pairs of stimuli compared. I understand this is an in-principle experimental constraint: much like voltage, we can't ask objective questions about single stimuli but rather only in comparison to a reference.
Returning to facial recognition via proximity in face space, we are worse at this for "kinds" of faces we've seen little of before*.
*I've linked the general effect but it happens at the visual level for face perception too: we're more prone to misidentifying individuals of races we didn't grow up with, and might even say "they all look the same" if we're racist
It seems learning improves 'fidelity' of regions of representational space, and different brains have undergone different learning. You could probably learn to distinguish chair colours better than currently. Then, if we show you two photos of a chair, whereas before they might activate the same "thought" (percept) in as much as you can't distinguish them, afterward you can, so those chairs are now represented by 'sufficiently different' points in your brain's chair space.
Given the brain's amazing potential for learning, and the fact your question is talking about all possible thoughts, I think the potential number is infinite. Maybe one brain at one snapshot in time could only have a finite number of distinguishable thoughts as defined above. If you instead define it by physical brain states e.g. as measured via electrodes, then those measures are continuous valued so the number of those is infinite (like the number of reals between 1 and 2 is infinite). But that feels a bit like saying the number of values a CPU transistor can take is infinite, because although we only read out 1 or 0, the actual voltages fluctuate.
I've not yet proofread this and wrote it from memory having left the field years ago

I find the neuro-scientific facts very interesting. It is funny that in the end the answer comes to the same conclusion as I did before, namely whether some unit (in the example here physical brain states measured via electrodes) is continuous or at least has infinite resolution.

it's a kind of varying resolution depending on where you are in the feature space (if you define resolution in terms of discriminability). But it is malleable to learning, so the number of possible thoughts (here conflated with percepts) is only limited by the number of learnable stimuli in the conceivable universe. Which seems boundless to me. It's funny how often philosophical claims about the internal mind find themselves invoking the entire external world nonetheless. Plato with his cave has already been mentioned. (re. physical brain states though, yeah neural firing rates are continuous)

another way of making the CPU point at the end: it has been routinely found that fairly different looking activity patterns (as measured via e.g. electrodes) have been found to correspond to the same "thought" (percept/action/etc) even within a single brain, within a single experimental session. This is just because the brain is imperfect and noisy. Otherwise we wouldn't need to take several fMRI scans of a subject and average over them or similar

Yes.
Consider the thought comprising the current date and time. At every moment, this will be a different thought - into eternity.

As I have said in the comments, how can you be sure that every date can be comprehended by a human. I mean if the year number is already too complex to be thought of, the date can also not be thought of.

@FlynnFehre, no need for infinitely many future or past discrete dates. In the same way you mentionned dividing the visible spectrum, there might be infinitely many time intervals in a day. If thougths include perceptions and the space-time is continuous and our perceptions are continuous too, then there are infinitely many thoughts I can have, and maybe already had.

I'm pretty sure this requires 'eternity' to be a real thing and I've not seen any proof for that.

@FlynnFehre You don't need to explicitly mention the number. " Let n_0 be the largest date anyone has thought so far", and then repeat the same words ad infinitum.

I'll give two different takes:

I don't believe it's true that a finite number of possible particles implies finitely many brain states.

It's not just the placement of particles, but their history.
Brain States aren't fixed in time, they refer to previous brain states. So, every new brain state generates more possible brain states.
The same way a finite number of digits can generate an infinite amount of numbers, the brain can generate an infinite amount of thoughts. - We can think about a thought, and think about thinking about a thought etc...

Humans will go extinct, and in our determenistic universe, every thought every human will have is determined.

So, as there are finitely many humans, existing for a finite amount of time.
The Set of evey thought that a human can have, is finite, and determines by the universes initial conditions.
These conditions force, only a finite amount of thoughts, and so there is a finite amount of thoughts which can occur.
Note: This two positions are compatible, they are using different notions of "possible"
